# I Need enable livereload in my coverage test report

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, code-coverage, grunt-contrib-connect

I've been trying enable livereload for my coverage report. 
My tool for generate this report is [karma-coverage](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage/blob/master/docs/configuration.md) and I generate this report in the following folder: **test/coverage/html-report**

```
 -test
 |
 |-- coverage
     |
     |-- report-html
         |
         |-- index.html
```

When the report was generated I use [grunt-contrib-connect](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect) and serve the generated report using the following:

```
 var COVERAGE_BASE = './test/coverage/report-html',

   ...
   ...
   ...
   connect: {
      server: {
        options: {
          port: 9000,
          base: '.',
          open: false
        }
      },
      dist:{
        options: {
          keepalive: true,
          port: 9000,
          base: './dist',
          open: false
        }
      },
      coverage: {
        options: {
          keepalive: true,
          port: 9001,
          base: COVERAGE_BASE ,
          open: false
        }
      }
    }
```

When I execute my task `grunt coverage`, my configuraton it's

```
COVERAGE_TASKS = ['shell:test','open:coverage', 'connect:coverage','watch'];

grunt.registerTask('coverage', COVERAGE_TASKS);
```

My idea it's "intercept" the index.html and inject a script to livereload

```
<script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```

Exist some way to intercept the index.html before serve with connect package and process it for adding this script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this helps:
you can add middle ware that can be used to intercept request to your connect server like this:

```js
grunt.initConfig({
  connect: {
    server: {
      options: {
        middleware: [
          function myMiddleware(req, res, next) {
            
            // DO YOUR THING HERE!!!!
            res.end('Hello, world!');
          }
        ],
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. How i read the index.html in this serve? it's part of the `res` argument?

Comment: No you might need to use nodejs fs module to open the html and replace what you want and serve it